# ListActivity and ActionBar in Android Studio

Tags: android, listactivity

I was working in Eclipse with ListCAtivity and getActionBar.
This is giving me error when I imported this project in Android Studio.Whats the way to use actionbar with List Activity.My styles.xml

```
 <style name="AppBaseTheme"      parent="Base.Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
</style>
<!-- Application theme. -->
<style name="AppTheme" parent="AppBaseTheme">
 <item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/MyActionBar</item>
</style>
```

Comment: You need to delete that "android:" part it's now lollipop's attribute

Answer (score 0):

Your Code should be like this

```
<style name="AppBaseTheme" parent="Base.Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar"/>

<!-- Application theme. -->
<style name="AppTheme" parent="AppBaseTheme">
   <item name="actionBarStyle">@style/MyActionBar</item>
</style>
```